# How to use scope bar with UISearchController

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uisearchcontroller

I am able to create scope bar to UISearchController & set their titles

```
    resultSearchController = ({

        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

        controller.searchResultsUpdater = self

        controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

        controller.searchBar.showsScopeBar = true

        controller.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["One", "two", "three"]

        controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()

        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar


        return controller

    })()
```

But how do I actually sort using scope bar. My current sorting method is as follows

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

    filteredTableData.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text)

    let array = (tableData as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)

    filteredTableData = array as! [String]

    tableView.reloadData()

}
```

Comment: please give more details,what output do you want?

Comment: if you see my code I am able to set scope bar titles. I want to sort results by three categories.

Comment: Do you have any data in `tableData` which would help in filtering using the scope bar?. `tableData` is just a array of strings, how would that help in filtering by "one", "two" or "three".

Comment: in the example provided above tableData is array of string. But I would like to have categories e.g. odd numbers, even numbers, All numbers. And that be title of the scope bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add search bar delegate as follows.

```
class NumberTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate {
```

Save register delegate in view did load as follows

```
resultSearchController.searchBar.delegate = self
```

Delegate has method to tell you which scope bar button is pressed as follows

```
    func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int) {

    filterArrayWithCharacterLength(selectedScope)

}
```

For detailed information check my tutorial on [How to add UISearchController to tableView](http://blog.apoorvmote.com/add-uisearchcontroller-to-tableview/)

Answer (score 0):

Even though late, it might help someone!
Suppose that you have an object Person and an array of filteredPeople where you keep People you've filtered, then

```
struct Person
{
  let name:String
}

func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController:UISearchController)
{
    //Start filtering only when user starts to write something
    if searchController.searchBar.text.length > 0
    {
        filteredPeople.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
        self.filterContentForSearchText(searchController.searchBar.text)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    else
    {
        self.filteredPeople = self.people
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String)
{
   self.filteredPeople = self.people.filter({( person: Person) -> Bool in

   //In this case we are searching for all, and the search is case insensitive      
   let categoryMatch = (scope == "All")
   let stringMatch = person.name.rangeOfString(searchText, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)
   return categoryMatch && (stringMatch != nil)
  })
}
```

Comment: This answer is very useful to me in this moment per just a question: the variable "scope" in method filterContentForSearchText(), where does it come from? it is declared nowhere...

Comment: I'm sorry for that!

 `let scopes = self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles as [String]`
`let scope = scopes[0]`

 // assuming that first scope is "All", otherwise you get the scope based on index in case you have more than one scope.

Comment: Thanks for the hint but you gave half ass attempt solving the problem. That's why I am not giving you the answer.